# How to install postgres using homebrew in apple Silicon?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, apple-silicon

I have installed postgres using installer link [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/)

And after that via homebrew

```
arch -x86_64 brew install postgresql
```

and then

```
arch -x86_64 brew reinstall postgresql
```

Error i am getting by running

```
 psql postgres
```

is

> psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused  Is the
> server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
> socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

and

```
arch -x86_64 brew services start postgresql
```

> Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error Error: Failure while
> executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/rajanlagah/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
> exited with 5.

Unable to find any blog or tutorial. How to install it ?

Comment: Do you have an older version of postgres installed?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue and realised the newer version conflicts with the data/cluster of a previously installed PostgreSql. You need to create a new cluster and before start your PostgreSql Server.

Rename existing directory:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/var/
mv /opt/homebrew/var/postgres postgres_backup
mkdir postgres
initdb .
```

When you run `initdb`, a new cluster is created.

Now, you should be able to start your PostgreSql Server by typing the following:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

To check if the server is running:

```
brew services
```

Now, you should be ale to see PostgreSql and other services and their statuses listed.